# How to get element value from htmx

Tags: django, htmx

I'm trying to move from using a `form` and `button` combination to using an `svg` with `htmx`.

This is the current way, this works:

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'posts:like_post' post.pk %}">
{% csrf_token %}
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <button type="submit" name='post_id' value="{{ post.id }}">Like</button>
{% else %}
    <a href="{% url 'pages:login' %}"><u>Login</u> to like</a>
{% endif %}
</form>
```

This is what I'm trying to move to, it doesn't work:

```
<svg hx-post="{% url 'posts:support_post' post.pk %}" hx-headers='{"X-CSRFToken": "{{ csrf_token }}"}' name='post_id' value="{{ post.id }}" class="some_class" xmlns=... /></svg>
```

As you can see both post requests end up at my `LikeView`:

```
def LikeView(request, pk):
    #post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=request.POST.get('post_id')) #This is the 'normal' (non-htmx) way that uses the form and button combo and works fine
    #post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=request.htmx.trigger_name) #This is where I'm stuck, I can get the name of the triggering element, 'post_id', but I can't get the value
```

Essentially I'm just trying to work out what I need to replace `request.POST.get('post_id')` with, in an htmx world.

Edit: I looked through here https://django-htmx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/middleware.html to get the `trigger_name` attribute but can't see anything about getting the value

Answer (score 1):

I have just started working with HTMX. And I had a similar need. I think the answer to your question lies in HTML standards and how form data is typically posted in HTML.

I know the [HTMX docs](https://htmx.org/docs/#parameters) say that every element's value will be included in the parameters. But web standards don't define name and value attributes for SVG elements. I think that's the root of your problem.

The docs also say that the [`hx-vals`](https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-vals/) attribute allows you to add to the parameters that will be submitted with an AJAX request. Try this:

```
    <svg hx-post="{% url 'posts:support_post' post.pk %}" hx-headers='{"X-CSRFToken": "{{ csrf_token }}"}' hx-vals='{"post_id": "{{ post.id }}"}' class="some_class" xmlns=... /></svg>
```

If that doesn't work, you can always resort to a form tag:

```
    <form>
      {% csrf_token %}
      <input type=hidden name=post_id value="{{ post.id }}">
      <svg hx-post="{% url 'posts:support_post' post.pk %}" class="some_class" xmlns=... /></svg>
    </form>
```

On a final note, far be it for me to preach about accessibility, but the svg tag you're putting in place of the button won't act like a button without some work that is out of the scope of your question.

Comment: Interesting, I'm still unclear how I would access the ```hx-vals``` value on the python side, I want to do something like ```request.htmx.trigger_value``` like I did for ```trigger_name```. However, to your point about my svg tag not behaving like a button without some work, I did not realise this so I may need to look into how i'd do this, or just lose the svg tag all along

Comment: According to the docs (https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-vals/), and I've tested in with a post. The JSON values in hx-vals are added to the resuest. In my case, they were added to the form's posted data. So `{ "some": "value_123" }` added a variable named `some` with a value of `value_123` as a POST variable.

I hop that helps.